# What tense do you use to refer to an adult's childhood as a child prodigy?

Tags: verbs, tenses

I'm currently writing a biography of a fictional character. Should I write "X is a child prodigy" or "X was a child prodigy" if X is currently an adult? My gut tells me to go with a past tense since X is no longer a child, but X is still outstanding in their field, so the prodigy part can still be refered to in present tense.

Comment: If X is an adult, you can say *X is prodigy* or *X was a child prodigy*, but your instinct is right: you cannot say *X is a child prodigy*.

Comment: @DanBron You can, of course, do anything you like. Thomas Carlyle, I believe, wrote his *History of the French Revolution* entirely in the present tense, even though it was about 40 years after the event.

Comment: @Ws2 My statement wasn't dealing in metaphysics or morality: it contained a tacit clause, omitted for the sake of brevity: *you cannot say "X is a child prodigy" ... and expect to be regarded as correct, or have that usage perceived as felicitous, by your anticipated audience*".

Comment: @Dan: *Shirley Temple is prodigy*??

Comment: @FumbleFingers You know copy-editing errors on frozen comments drive me crazy. Don't tickle my neuroses, please. And of all the potential child prodigies you could have picked as exemplars ... *Shirley Temple*, really?

Comment: @Dan: Not my finest hour, I admit. But all the other famous ones that came to mind were dead long before the Internet, so it wouldn't mean much. All these typos - are you staking a claim to my handle when I shuffle off this mortal coil? (Or just saving up for a full-size bluetooth keyboard for your handheld? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not just the keyboard, it's the damn thing *fights* me to type or fix anything. It auto-incorrects (auto-corrupts?) like every third word, and then makes moving the cursor around, selecting words, copying, pasting, etc, nigh impossible. You should see what these notes look like as I'm typing them (there, it just added a period after "these" and capitalized "notes", then changed the `t` in *typing* to a `5`, and to add insult to injury ignored the `s` in *these* in this parenthetical explanatory comment, and I won't even tell you what it just changed *parenthetical* to!).

Comment: @DanBron - That doesn't happen to me (I have different problems).  I wonder if your mouse is hypersensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on which tense you use in your narrative.  Usually a biography is related from the temporal point of view of the writer's present, so the past events are placed in the past tense:

> X was born in 1922 and X began school at the age of 3.  By the age of 4, X was posing and
>   answering questions that stumped his teachers.  Everyone realized that
>   X **was** a child prodigy.

But nothing precludes the biographer from adopting the present time of the events:

> X is born in 1922 and begins school at the age of 3.  By the age of 4, X is posing and
>   answering questions that stump his teachers.  Everyone realizes that
>   X **is** a child prodigy.

Changing the temporal point of view of the narrative changes the tense of the verbs, but of course, it doesn't alter the fact that past events have already happened.

What you can't do is describe the adult X as a child prodigy during the time X is an adult.

Comment: +1 for "*What you can't do is describe the adult X as a child prodigy during the time X is an adult*", which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: [Shirley Temple was a child prodigy](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22shirley+temple+was+a+child+prodigy%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) gets 8 hits on Google, but [the same quoted string with **is**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22shirley+temple+is+a+child+prodigy%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) gets no hits at all. Okay, at least 2 of the 8 are after she died last year, but it's still strong evidence of what form is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the present tense, you could say that the person is a *former child prodigy*.

It sounds clunky, but it's used surprisingly often. There are many "where are they now" articles that use the phrase *former child prodigy* to refer to an adult who was a prodigy as a child.

Comment: I don't quite like this because it implies that the success and skill they had as a child is no longer a part of them.

Comment: I understand and sort of agree, but the fact is it's a widely used phrase. Also, it's technically correct, because you can't be a child prodigy unless you're a child, and nobody stays a child. A child a prodigy is a young child who exhibits a level of ability in a field which is typical of a talented adult. Being able to do calculus at age 3 is prodigious, but being able to do calculus at 30 is pretty mundane.